# Spring removes whitespace when converting Strings to Longs

Tags: spring

I'm working on a project using Spring 3.1. We're doing all our validation server side but are running into an issue when a request parameter is bound to a Long or Integer object. While most invalid values ultimately result in an exception and an error message is displayed, this is not the case when the request parameter contains whitespace between digits. For example, when binding "12345 6789", we would expect a validation error but instead the whitespace is just getting trimmed out.

I've used the debugger to find that this is occurring in org.springframework.util.NumberUtils. A StringUtils.trimAllWhitespace is called to remove the whitespace from all input. This seems like a common enough use-case but I've so far been unable to find anyone who has a good solution. What would be the best way to do a simple conversion of the String on the request parameters to Long or Integer while only accepting digits?

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to create a custom validator that will meet your needs.

Example taken from the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC3/reference/html/ch05s07.html):

**Constraint declaration:**

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy=MyConstraintValidator.class)
public @interface MyConstraint {
}
```

**Constraint implementation**

```
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;

public class MyConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator {

    @Autowired;
    private Foo aDependency;

    ...
}
```

**Edit:**

Creating a custom property converter [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.5/reference/mvc.html).

@Controller
public class MyFormController {

```
    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        dateFormat.setLenient(false);
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, false));
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. From what I can tell though, validation occurs after binding has occurred so I can't validate the incoming String, only the Long where it is too late the catch the whitespace.

Comment: Yes you're right, so a way to workaround your problem would be to create your own property converter (from String to Long while checking for whitespace). Here is the link to the doc http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/validation.html

Comment: Check section 5.4.2.1 Registering additional custom PropertyEditors

Comment: Thanks, this is looking like it might be the only solution although we were hoping to avoid this. We would really prefer a solution that could be applied on a field by field basis. A custom PropertyEditor is either registered for all Longs or specific fields in the InitBinder, we would rather mark specific fields through an annotation in our domain object. I looked into converters and formatters as well, but Spring fails over to the default CustomNumberEditor when an exception is thrown from either.