# Cannot change field value when using ConstraintValidator

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation

I followed the approach mentioned on [Spring removes whitespace when converting Strings to Longs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13978614/spring-removes-whitespace-when-converting-strings-to-longs) in order to trim some String fields via **annotation** as shown below:

```
@Data
public class EmployeeRequest {

    @MyConstraint(field = "name") // ???
    public String name;
}
```

However, I cannot trim the name field and receive it with whitespace in my service. I also checked the documentation page, but could not understand what I am missing:

***MyConstraint:***

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy=MyConstraintValidator.class)
public @interface MyConstraint {

    String field();
}
```

***MyConstraintValidator:***

```
public class MyConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MyConstraint, String> {

    @Autowired
    private String aDependency; // what is this dependency?

    private String field;

    public void initialize(IsLessThan constraintAnnotation) {

        // I tried to trim value at here
        this.field = constraintAnnotation.field().trim();
    }

    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {

        Object fieldValue = new BeanWrapperImpl(value).getPropertyValue(field);

        return true; // I return true as I do not need to validate field value
    }
}
```

So, what is wrong with this implementation?

Comment: Ofcourse you cannot. It is for validation not for changing values.

Comment: I know that. But why not? I think I can get the value in the `initialize()` method and then manipulate it. Is that not possible?

Comment: Because its use case is validation **not** binding/changing values. It will only read values not set them back into the objects. Next to that you shouldn't abuse a validation framework for that.

Comment: Additionally, `initialize(IsLessThan constraintAnnotation)` should be `initialize(MyConstraint constraintAnnotation)`.

Comment: @M.Deinum I know it is not a right way, but just needed to make something via this approach. On the other hand, are you sure that it is not changed (field value)? Did you have  a look at that page, it seems as it can be changed. Any idea?

Comment: Last time: no you cannot change the field value. The link you refer to doesn't change anything, it bypasses the default binding from spring and does its own validation, which is different from your use case. If you want to trim whitespaces register the proper propertyeditor in your binder (if binding form-data to an object) or use a proper deserializer for your json library when binding the request body.

Comment: Thanks a lot, in this scene I can follow "registering  the proper property editor in my binder" as you mentioned. Could you please post an example?